# tags of axis ticks are truncated with pandas/matplotlib plot

Tags: python

I am using pandas (matplotlib in the background) to create some histogram.

I am doing it roughly like this:

```
output = StringIO.StringIO()
plot_canvas = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ax = plot_canvas.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

series = df[key].value_counts()[:nums]
fig = series.plot(ax=ax, kind="bar", colormap="Blues",
                  legend=False,
                  stacked=False,
                  title="Numbers of %s" % key,
                  grid=True).get_figure()
fig.savefig(output, format="png")
o_data = output.getvalue()
output.close()
image_data = o_data.encode("base64")
image_uri = 'data:image/png;base64,%s' % image_data
```

My problem is, that the X data are names (string) which are rather long and which are with these default settings truncated in the PNG. So I wonder, how I can move the graph in the plotting are, to get more free space unterneath the graph.

[image]

You can see that the strings at the X axis are truncated.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple automated [solution](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html):

`plot_canvas.tight_layout()`

You can also define the axis rectangle when creating the subplot, by passing a `rect` keyword argument to `add_subplot` the format `[left, bottom, width, height]`.

Comment: If you've done `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` you can also access this via `plt.tight_layout()`.

Comment: Something like this should work `plt.tight_layout(rect=(0, 0.25, 1, 1))`

Comment: Does it matter where `plt.tight_layout()` is called?